# Disable zoom on input focus, like Gmail login screen

Tags: javascript, forms, user-interface, responsive-design, gmail

I have a question regarding zooming on a responsive website, when focusing an input field.

What I'd like is the same effect that they have on the Gmail login page when trying to sign on an iPhone. Like this: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&continue=https://mail.google.com

If you try going to that URL on your phone, you can see that it's generally possible to zoom in on the page, but when focusing on the one of the two input fields, the browser doesn't automatically zoom in, like it normally does on other forms.

Can anyone explain to me how this effect can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

May seem odd, but if you change the font size it wont do it. (16px might not be the right font size just tinker with that)

```
input{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I totally understand. So I change the font-size on focus? Like input:focus og just in the input-field in genneral?

Comment: just in the input-field in general. But 16px might not be the right size

Comment: The 16px limit will only work if the website is not zoomed (out) by default. If the page (body) is broader than 320 pixels and width=device-width and the page is shown on iPhone in portrait mode, than this will not work.